# loop: Replacing value at a certain position

Tags: r, loops, replace

I have one matrix and one vector and want to change the values at the position of the matrix where the value in the vector is negative.

```
x <- c(1,-5,4,-8,9)

X <- matrix(c(5,7,3,
              -5,6,8,
              9,-6,4,
              2,-1,-3,
              5,2,4),byrow=TRUE, nrow=5)
```

for all the values of x which are i<0 take the position and multiply at this position in X the whole row with -1

This should be the result:

```
X2 <- matrix(c(5,7,3,
               5,-6,-8,
               9,-6,4,
               -2,1,3,
               5,2,4),byrow=TRUE, nrow=5)
```

this is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
if (x[i] > 0) {
  X[i, ] <- (- X[i, ])
}
print(X)
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you need a loop, just try this.

```
X * sign(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x <- c(1,-5,4,-8,9)

X <- matrix(c(5,7,3,
              -5,6,8,
              9,-6,4,
              2,-1,-3,
              5,2,4),byrow=TRUE, nrow=5)

x
X
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if (x[i] < 0) {
    X[i, ] <- - X[i, ]
  }
}
X
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  if (x[i] < 0) {
    X[i, ] <- -X[i, ]
  }
}

print(X)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    3
[2,]    5   -6   -8
[3,]    9   -6    4
[4,]   -2    1    3
[5,]    5    2    4
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(1,-5, 4, -8, 9)
X <- matrix(
  c(5, 7, 3, -5, 6, 8, 9,-6, 4, 2, -1, -3, 5, 2, 4),
  byrow=TRUE,
  nrow=5
)
```